# Gmapping for Building a Map

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) package for building a map.

My tf tree is complete: `map --> odom --> robot/base_footprint --> robot /base_link --> robot/laser`

`map --> odom` is broadcast by `/slam_gmapping` and `odom --> robot/base_footprint` is broadcast by `/ekf_localization`

At the beginning I was getting the following warning message:

```
MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information
```

I set the DEBUG mode in rqt, and I got the following message:

```
 MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Added message in frame laser at time 1414977417.595, count now 5
```

using [this therad](http://answers.ros.org/question/9353/issue-with-setting-tf-in-gmapping/). I set `rosparam set use_sim_time true`, and the warning message disappeared, but the DEBUG mode is still showing the message above.

Nothing is published to `/map` topic.

Laser is published to `robot/scan`

I am not sure if I have to set the frame id for my laser which is `robot/laser` or not. gmapping does not seem to have such a parameter, but I have set

```
 <param name="base_frame" value="robot/base_footprint"/>
 <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
```

I have also set in my launch file:

```
<arg name="scan_topic" default="robot/scan" />
<remap from="scan" to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
```

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196522/gmapping-for-building-a-map/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gmapping's default topic for scandata is "scan". you are using instead "robot/scan".
so just remap the topic in your launchfile (i assume you use one):

```
<remap from="scan" to="robot/scan" />
```

or in your terminal:

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=robot/scan
```

---

Originally posted by [lebowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20622/lebowski/) with karma: 146 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-03**:
I'm actually remapping the scan topic in my launch file.

**Comment by [lebowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20622/lebowski/) on 2014-11-03**:
please open rviz and

1. set "fixed frame" to "odom"
2. add display type tf
3. add laserscan -> set topic to "robot/scan"

lets see if any errors/warnings appear